# Fourier transform (The 1-D neutron diffusion equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

The $1-D$ neutron diffusion equation with a (plane) source is

$-D\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}}\varphi (x) }{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}+K^{2}D\varphi (x)=Q\delta (x)$

where $\varphi (x)$ is the neutron flux, $Q\delta (x)$ is the (plane) source at $x = 0$ and $D$ and $K^2$ are
constants. Apply a Fourier transform. Solve the equation in transform space. Transform your solution back into x-space.

*ANS*:$\varphi (x)=\frac{Q}{2KD}e^{-|Kx|}$

Comment: What is your question exactly?, Which part of exercise is difficult for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$-D\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}}\varphi (x) }{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}+K^{2}D\varphi (x)=Q\delta (x)$$
Apply Fourier Transform:
 $$\mathcal {F}\{ f'(x)\}=iw \mathcal{F}\{f\}(w) \text { , and } \mathcal {F}\{\delta(x)\}=1$$
$$-(iw)^2\varphi (w) +K^{2}\hat {\varphi } (w)=\frac Q D$$
$$(w^2 +K^{2})\hat {\varphi }(w)=\frac Q D$$
$$\hat {\varphi } (w)=\frac Q {D(w^2 +K^{2})}$$
$$\hat {\varphi } (w)=\frac Q {2KD} \frac {2K} {(w^2 +K^{2})}$$
Now apply Inverse Fourier Transform:
$$\mathcal{F^{-1}} \left \{\frac {2K} {(w^2 +K^{2})}\right \}=e^{-K|x|} \text { , with } K>0$$
$$\varphi (x)=\frac Q {2KD} e^{-K |x|} $$